# nginx headers not added

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, backend

I'm trying to add CORS headers to my nginx server. I tried the following:

```
include mime.types;

server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name #domain;
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
server_name #domain;

location / {
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
                add_header Strict-Transport-Security “max-age=15768000” always;
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
        }
        if ($request_method ~* '(POST|GET|PUT|PATCH|DELETE)') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS';
                add_header Strict-Transport-Security “max-age=15768000” always;
        }
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;

}

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;

ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:5m;
ssl_session_timeout 1h;
}
```

But while GET and OPTIONS have their headers added, the other methods don't.
I saw that headers are only added if there are not on the previous level so I tried to have them all at the same level.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Since `OPTIONS` is the only preflight one and the rest of the verbs are all the same you can just get rid of the `if` statement altogether so it is always added.

Comment: I did try removing the `if` but they still don't get added. I'm not sure where the problem comes from

Comment: @AnassElidrissi Have you tried using `always` in the `add_header` directives?